# Figure out Type of target object of MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception

I'm loading some data asynchronously. Loaded data is not any specific type but it requires parameterless constructor. Now I forgot about it and the

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

exception was catch. The problem is I don't know what is "**this object**"?? Well in current situation I know what is the type because I just added it but I see future problems here. 
How can I figure out type of object that caused the problem? Should I check for the constructor first and throw my own Exception before calling `Activator.CreateInstance()`? That seem like double check of the same thing and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Does `ClassName` have the info? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.missingmemberexception.classname?view=netframework-4.7.2 - note: if you're targeting netstandard, this doesn't appear until netstandard2.0

Comment: The `ClassName` is `null` in my case. I use net framework 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I check for the constructor first and throw my own Exception before calling `Activator.CreateInstance()`?

Calling `Activator.CreateInstance` requires a type. Is there any specific reason you can't use a solution like this one?

```
public object Create(Type type)
{
    try
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
    catch (MissingMethodException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Gotcha! Type: {type}");
        // or whatever handling, eg. rethrow with type included:
        throw new MyException(type, e);
    }
}
```